# Using Proximity from Curve to control Volume Shader in Cube

Tags: materials, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, volumetrics

I'm experimenting with the Geometry Proximity node in Geo Nodes, using Blender version 3.2.1. The effect I want to achieve is a volumetric shader within a cube domain that is controlled by the distance from a Curve.

I can achieve the effect I'm looking for on the surface of the cube (see figure below). You can see the Bezier curve poking out of the left face and the front face of the cube. Small distances to the curve are colored blue on the faces of the cube with larger distances colored green and red. This test case of a surface shader appears to work fine.

[image]

However, when I plug the Emission Shader into the Volume socket on the Material Output node the volume is colored a uniform blue inside the cube.

Any ideas why this setup works for a surface shader but not a volume shader? Maybe this use case isn't supported yet by Geometry Proximity? Or perhaps a setting or setup I'm not using correctly?

Blend file attached below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There is no geometry (no points, no edges, no faces) inside the cube, so there is nothing for the Geometry Proximity node to reference when calculating Distance values from the points on the Bezier curve.

I've experimented with creating a 3d grid of points positioned inside the cube, but so far no luck.

I'm still interested in solutions or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way!

its a bit of a workaround, but it does work.

So basically, you use the new-ish Volume Cube node, this allows you to plug a field into the density value. You can plug your proximity node into that and transform it a little bit with map ranges. Then, you can go into the shader editor and use the volume info node, that density value is the equivalent to your proximity, meaning you can use it however you'd like.

I've added a picture showing how it works, if my explanation wasnt clear. (I added a glowing material for the curve so you can see where it is)

I hope this helps anyone, even though im a little bit late.

[image]